# Login Control suddenly stopped working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, charts

Here is my connection string:

```
  <add name="modelConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='D:\Documents and Settings\Dima\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite10\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;Trusted_Connection=Yes;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Here is my membership config section

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
         connectionStringName="modelConnectionString"
         minRequiredPasswordLength="1"
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
         enablePasswordReset="true"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="1000" 
         passwordAttemptWindow="4000" 
         enablePasswordRetrieval="true" 
         requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
         passwordFormat="Encrypted" 
         applicationName="/WebSite10"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

I was searching in google for 2 hours and found nothing related that would solve this issue. The control worked for 2 months and then stopped suddenly

Comment: Could you post the error message?

Comment: is it giving an error or just not logging in?

Comment: I get the login error. You cant login try again...It is the default error the login erorr writes when you cant login...

Answer (score 1):

for sql membership to work you need to register the sql database for membership.

Make sure you execute `aspnet_regsql.exe -A m -E` from the command line

full instructions [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197472%28office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: How could i reset the whole databse..??

Comment: open the visual studio command prompt usually found in the programs menu under Visual studio [Version] -> Visual STudio Tools

Comment: I have no visual studio tools folder

Comment: sorry , i see it..D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a SQL User Instance, did you change the identity of the site's application pool in IIS?  Or if you are using the development server, are you logged in as a different user?

See: [SQL Server 2005 Express Edition User Instances](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264564%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

---

If you are getting the message you posted above then I would guess your membership provider is working properly with the DB, and the problem lies within the actual aspnet membership tables in the database.

First if you don't already have it, get [Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8961) so you can work with your MDF file.

Then you can look for issues in the `dbo.aspnet_Users` table, and execute stored procedures such as `aspnet_Users_CreateUser` and `aspnet_Users_DeleteUser`.

If you run into something that looks abnormal in there, just update your question and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: No, i was the same user. The web.config works fine..i tested it on an old copy of my site.. I think something inside the databases got really wrong, and one of its definitions has changed..Is there a way then to reset the database..To delete all the users etc.?